# Materialized view needs to be compiled or refresh

Tags: sql, oracle, materialized-views

I have below script to create Materialized view with two tables involved.

I see data is automatically reflected when there a new data inserted in source tables after 24 hours as i mentioned REFRESH in my script .

Do i still need to refresh the Materialized view manually or This script is enough to take care of auto refresh . I am in confusion , please advise .

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW MVW_ITEM (Item_id ,Item_cost )
BUILD IMMEDIATE
USING INDEX
REFRESH COMPLETE START WITH SYSDATE+0 next SYSDATE + 1
USING DEFAULT LOCAL ROLLBACK SEGMENT
USING ENFORCED CONSTRAINTS DISABLE QUERY REWRITE

select Item_id , Item_cost from item_dict , item_dtls

where item_dict.item_id = item_dtls.item_id;
```

Comment: If a refresh once per day is sufficient for your application then you are fine. Otherwise you need to refresh manually or change the refresh period.

Comment: Thanks, but i dont want to create a job and run the job to refresh the M-View . I want to refresh the M-VIEW on its own every 24 hours once by using 'Refresh' command .  . can you pls advise whether the above script will work for my scenario.

Comment: Not clear what you mean. Do you like to refresh manually every 24 hours or do you like it refreshed automatically every 24 hours? For a manual refresh you don't need to configure any job. For an automatic refresh you don't need any manual refresh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `start with ... next ...` in the MV definition automatically creates a job to refresh it for you.

So yes, the database will automatically refresh the MV for you every day given using `START WITH SYSDATE+0 next SYSDATE + 1` (though there's no need to add zero to the start). No further action is needed from you.

You can view this job by querying `*_scheduler_jobs` (`*_jobs` on older versions).

```
create table t (
  c1 int
);

create materialized view mv 
refresh start with sysdate next sysdate + 1
as 
  select count(*) from t;
  
select job_name, job_action, start_date, next_run_date 
from   user_scheduler_jobs;

JOB_NAME           JOB_ACTION                               START_DATE                                      NEXT_RUN_DATE                         
MV_RF$J_0_S_172    dbms_refresh.refresh('"CHRIS"."MV"');    20-JUN-2023 09.57.13.000000000 EUROPE/LONDON    21-JUN-2023 09.57.13.000000000 GMT
```